# How to export a variable from sh step to outside sh step in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to email the output of a file after a build. The build updates the file file1.json. Her is my problem. After build I am trying to create a variable which cat the file1.json ( this is working) , then I am trying to email that variable in emailext.

```
Stage {
       stage('Build'){\
         sh """
            npm install // builds and update the value in json file 
            UUID="`cat file1.json`"  //outputs the string inside file which is what I want 
            echo \$UUID //shows the value here
         """
         emailext body:  "$UUID", //need the value here 
           subject: "$currentBuild.currentResult-$JOB_NAME",
           to: 'someone@test.com'
} 
`
The error message is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: UUID for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option `returnStdout: true` of `sh()` step to get the output of shell.

```
stage('Build'){

    script {

        sh 'npm install' // builds and update the value in json file 

        UUID = sh (script: 'cat file1.json', returnStdout: true).trim()

        emailext body:  "$UUID",  subject: "$currentBuild.currentResult-$JOB_NAME", to: 'someone@test.com'
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you Yong